# Any quirks on Virtuozzo VPS?

Tags: hosting, webserver, hosting-providers

The good news,  I'm returning to the cloud provider that I used for many years. (I left because I merged my business with another firm.) Here's where I'm a little uncertain. The provider I've been using for the past few months runs their VPS farm with Virtuozzo, which has been incompatible with other tools I use for server admin (not web development). I have a handful of odd behaviors and buggy behavior that I can't quite fix. I'm wondering if this might be the servers. Has someone else seen oddball stuff while using similar VPS  environments? Might I expect these problems to go away when we move? (One user is tied to the virtuozzo system and if that's our problem, I need to get them away.) Thanks in advance.